# Magento 1.8 - Add Coupon Code programatically

Tags: php, magento

I want to have a Model Window on my website in which the user can sign up to our newsletter.  Once the user has entered their email address and successfully subscribed I want to automatically add the coupon code to their cart.

I have the following script, but when I run it and refresh my cart, it doesn't add the discount:

```
<?php

  require_once 'app/Mage.php';
  umask(0);
  Mage::app();

  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode('ks92yor7')->collectTotals()->save();

?>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the core/session to frontend.

After `Mage:app();`:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```